# Entity Framework update a column and get old value in atomic operation

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

Is it possible with entity framework to update a column and get the old value before updating in an atomic operation?

Searching for something like Mongo Update with `Document.Before`, but for entity framework.

Comment: "old value" in memory or on disk?

Comment: in the database, basically I want to update a column and know the value of the column before the update, I need to check if it was NULL or it had another value before updating.

Comment: In T-SQL you can add an [OUTPUT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) clause to the `UPDATE` operation. That's not exposed in EF. You can use raw SQL or create a stored procedure that does what you want and map to it

Comment: As to my knowledge with EF there's no way you can know the actual value of the column before updating it

Answer (score 0):

This might help you. 
Make use of `Transaction` for the `Concurrency` control.

```
Foo newFoo = new Foo() {
    FooId = 2,
    FooName = "John"
}

FooEntity foo = context.Foo.FirstOrDefault(b => b.FooId);
```

The above code will gives you the `FooEntity` data and you can update the data as below.

```
foo.FooName = newFoo.FooName;
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Those are 2 separate queries, in the meanwhile the value could have been changed by another query.

Comment: @UberFace Will create any issue for you if you use `Transaction`?

Comment: hi! You mean dbContext.BeginTransaction()? was now aware I had such a tool. Yeah it would work I think thank you

Comment: @UberFace Yes. :)